# Can I use switches or must I use PoE Extenders/Switches to extend PoE cables

Tags: switch

I have a 120'x60' metal bldg that I'm adding security cameras to.  To keep the cat8 cables at 30m or less, I wanted to know if I have to use PoE switches in the middle before terminating the cables in the actual PoE switch where my internet begins? Can I add a switch in a central location for a PoE camera system to keep my cable lengths manageable or do I have to use a PoE switch in the center as well?

Comment: Why 30 meters and Cat8? These are security cameras. They need only a small amount of bandwidth and that will run easily over just about any Ethernet cable and at least 100 meters. Unless you somehow found a 200 megapixel camera with 120 FPS you’re not going anywhere close to the 25Gbps that would limit you to Cat8 and 30 meters.

Comment: PoE usually has shorter effective distances before the power levels drop off.

Comment: @Appleoddify - I appreciate the detailed question/info.  I was given Cat8 and used it to wire my home.  30m is longest recommended Cat8 cable  from manufacture because of speed drops, yet I've not been able to find out if that drop is detrimental.  I have about 300m of Cat8 cable and was using what I had vs buying Cat5/6/7;  I know these are  less expensive & will allow greater lengths.

Comment: @music2myear -thank you;  that's what I thought and I didn't want more drop with a longer cable.

Answer (score 1):

You only need POE on the switches connecting to the end devices. POE simply injects power into the cable (alongside the data signals).

A POE switch connected to another POE switch will work, but the POE part won't be used (unless you were powering the second switch with POE, but that could not be the case here.

Also, are you really sure you should be using cat8? I've not used it, but if you are using it for POE it would not seem to provide a significant benefit over cat7 (and are cameras ever going to need more the the gigabit provided by cat6?)

Comment: Thank you for the response,  I have about 300m of Cat8 and was using it vs buying Cat5/6/7 for their length.  Based on the response it appears it would be more cost effective and meet my length requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying.  It would be wasteful, but I'm fairly sure Cat8 cable can be used for longer distances then 30 meters, it just wont perform at 25 gig.   That said, I wonder if what you have is real Cat8 cable - this retails for  US$800 per 300m length, and I just checked a major New Zealand cable supplier I have a wholesale account with and they don't even sell Cat7 or Cat8 cable (and while it must exist I could not find any roles of Cat8 cable on Amazon either)

Comment: I got the cable from someone who has access through their company which happens to be a major internet provider.  Numerous online sources have Cat8 in bulk as well.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Cat8-Network-Cable-Entegrade/dp/B07WCCJZR9/ref=asc_df_B07WCCJZR9/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=397133308031&hvpos=1o13&hvnetw=g&hvrand=6894419665253350078&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9030650&hvtargid=pla-841186250089&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=80571461181&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=397133308031&hvpos=1o13&hvnetw=g&hvrand=6894419665253350078&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9030650&hvtargid=pla-841186250089 for:  $581.08; not sure of it's quality.

Comment: Interesting find.  They don't have it in stock but its $499 on their websit (although with 1 good and 1 bad review!)